# How to save variables and use these in another page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm making a website with a guest and admin side to it. In the admin side there are additional page's in which you can fill in form's which contain text and titles for certain div's in other page's.

I was wondering how can I make it so that when you fill in these forms and press save, the variables will be used in the other page where you can actually see the title and text as html. The text and title have to be visible for everyone that visits the page and have to stay there until there are changes made.

I have code yet, since i don't know how to start, I do have the interfaces, you can see the HTML down here.

Interface Input:

```
   <div class="panel-box">

    <div class="titles">
        <h4>Voeg vacatures toe</h4>
    </div>
    <form class="form-theme">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="name">Titel vacature</label>
                    <input type="text"  required="required" value="" maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="Name" id="name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="description">Beschrijving</label>
                    <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" required="required" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Output:

```
  <!-- Content Central -->
    <div class="container padding-top">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- content Column Left -->
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <!-- Experts -->
                <div class="panel-box">
                    <div class="titles">
                        <h4> <!-- This is where the title should be --> </h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <ul class="events-carousel events-no-carousel">
                            <!-- Item blog post -->
                            <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <div class="info-post">
                                    <h4><a href="vacancy.twig">Vacature naam</a></h4>
                                    <p><!-- This is where the text should be -->
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="{{ path('static_page', {template:'club/vacancy'}) }}">Bekijken</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <!-- End Item blog post -->
                        </ul>
                        <!-- End blog post-->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Experts -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Testimonials -->
    <!-- End Section Area - Content Central -->
```

Comment: for example.. http://devzone.zend.com/14/php-101-part-9-sqlite-my-fire_part-1/

Comment: it is a good way yes, but not the way i'm searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you should store your form data in database, and then retrieve it from database to render on the other page.

So the PHP script on the page with form should save your form data, when other script on page where you want to show your data should take it from database.

Comment: I was told there was another way, without a database. I would first like to try that. the problem is i don't really remember what the way was even though ive searched the internet. [Also I dont have a db for this project yet, and am still waiting as the deadline closes in.]

Comment: @Anona In any case you have to save your data somewhere. It can be database, for example, MySQL or SQLite, or it can be just file, but you will not implement your idea without storage.

Comment: Ah mkay, Thanks a lot ill see what I can do

Comment: without a database... you can always use a csv or json file... but it would be much simpler to just use a sqlite DB (as linked in my comment). You dont want to take care of all the filehandling/locking you will run into

Comment: Okey thanks, to both of you!! I'll ask my intern coordinators (dont know the english word for it ) for a db